# install Crystall Reports in Client Machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, crystal-reports

I've created a project with Crystal Reports 13 with it , I want to install Crystal Reports Runtime in the client machine but i can't find any working link in the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded both files from the following links and scanned them with an up to date NOD32 Antivirus.  No threats were found.  I found the link by searching Google for Crystal Reports 13 Runtime.

64bit
http://downloads.i-theses.com/index.php?option=com_downloads&task=downloads&groupid=9&id=101

32Bit
http://downloads.i-theses.com/index.php?option=com_downloads&task=downloads&groupid=9&id=100